# Error response from daemon: get nvidia_driver_375.66: no such volume: nvidia_driver_375.66

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I proceeded trouble shooting for tensorflow can't use GPU in docker. I find nvidia driver DSO files is 375.66, incompatible with my current version 375.26. So I deleted the dir `/var/lib/nvidia-docker/volumes/nvidia_driver/367.66`. But when I closed the container, I can't rerun it again.

I reinstall the nvidia driver, cuda, nvidia-docker for many times. When I start the container, it always echoes the error:
    `Error response from daemon: get nvidia_driver_375.66: no such volume: nvidia_driver_375.66`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, make dir-tree under 'var/lib/',like this: 'nvidia-docker/volumes/nvidia_driver/'. uninstall nvidia-docker properly, and re-install it again, the 375.66 dir back again.